# Executor Thread still shown in CPU

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm working on a problem where I'm posting tasks into executor for every instance, and once its work is over the instance is getting cleared from the memory, I took the memory dump after series of forced garbage collection but could not able to find any instance of one who is holding executor. But still I can see that the thread created by executor is still present in CPU but in sleeping state, and it there for the app lifetime, I don't know how to clear it or remove it from the CPU.

This case is not happening everytime, sometime it is getting cleared from memory sometime not. But majorly it is getting cleared. But if this keeps happening then the device may end up giving OutOfMemory(OOMs) crash because it would not be able to create more threads.

I tried calling `shutdown()` method on executor that also seems to be not working.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    MyThread(Runnable r, String name) {
        super(r, name);
    }
}
```

```
class YourThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    int thread = -1;

    YourThreadFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        thread = SomeStaticClass.thread++;
        return new MyThread(r, "MyThread " + thread);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize(); 
        Log.d("ThreadFactory",  Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " " + " Executor removed " + thread);

    }
}
```

```
ExecutorService mSingleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new YourThreadFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you're doing it wrong:

1. You shouldn't use finalize() ever
2. You shouldn't create more ExecutorService instances in your application, best practice is to have just one ExecutorService instance in whole application
3. shutdown() method of ExecutorService works, it just waits until all submitted tasks have been terminated: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: I'm not using finalize(), its just to know whether it is getting called or not. And if it  is called then I'm doing profiling to check whether that thread is still there in the CPU or not.

Comment: Ok, fair point. Btw check this post which will IMHO answer all your questions about executors: https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should probably tie this thread to the scope of the android application (Assuming this is android related as you have an android tag). You can use `interrupt` and then set the thread instance to null maybe.

For a custom thread maybe you could:

```
public void stopThread(){
  if(thread !=null){
      thread.interrupt();
      thread = null;
  }
}
```

and ideally, tie it to `onDestroy`.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` which will at most create just one thread. If your application reaches the kernel limit for maximum threads then something is creating threads, not this lone `ExecutorService` object which only has one thread.

Do note that you should create a single instance of `ExecutorService` for your tasks and use [`submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) to enqueu tasks. `ExecutorService` is not a `Thread` wrapper. Executors are used to define the concurrency level in your application by defining thread pools.

If you can't shut down `ExecutorService` with `shutdown()` it means there is task being processed. You can terminating by calling [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) but your tasks will get interrupted.

Comment: In my use case for every instance creates I've few tasks that I want to execute concurrently but no two instances are related and they can be run separately. Thats the reason I'm creating instances on every instance creation.

Comment: While clearing my instance I'm calling shutdown of executor and its finalized is also called but I can still see that thread in CPU

Comment: IMHO that's more of a use-case of [`ComplatableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and not separate `ExecutorService`